# Find a Martingale in a game of exchanging hats

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

$n$ people play a game of exchanging hats, with the following two rules:

--They throw their hats in to a pile and everyone chooses one uniformly at random, those who got back their own hat are out of the game.

--This is repeated until everyone has its own hat back.

Let $R$ denote the number of rounds the game takes to ﬁnish. $R = 1$ means that everyone got their own hat back at the ﬁrst drawing. Calculate the expected number of rounds $E[R]$.

I think the key is to find a martingale $S_n$ with respect to a random sequence $X_n$, such that $E(S_n|X_1, X_2,...,X_{n-1})=S_{n-1}$. Thus we could regard $R$ as a stopping time, and there's a normal way to solve $E[R]$. However I cannot figure out what can be the martingale $S_n$ in this question, and what can be the $\{X_n\}$ .

Any help would be appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected number is n.

The question was solved using an induction method in

[The Matching Rounds Problem--Proof by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177851/the-matching-rounds-problem-proof-by-induction/1177918#1177918)